# How to measure the short-time change in an audio signal?

Tags: audio, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, mfcc, cepstral-analysis

The choice of frame length for calculating the Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients of a signal, depend on the how much the signal change over a small time scale.
I guess that human speech change rapidity while some animal sound change more slowly, but what is the measure of small time scale of an audio signal?

Comment: Window length depends on the kind of signal you want to analyze. What is your audio signal composed of?

Comment: It is underwater recording made by hydrophones e.g. of whales. The signal of interest starts at ca. 100 hz and then raises too 250 hz in 1-2 seconds, but do contain noise

Comment: ok .. and what's your problem statement? what do you want to do with this audio?

Comment: I am doing binary classification of audio files; if they contain the sound of a whale, they are labeld positive otherwise negative.
For this purpose I have implemented classifier using Hidden markov models, and as features I use the cepstral coefficients, but for calculting these I need to settle on a frame length.
Related work wich use a similar approach for speech recognition, use a frame length of 45ms. But I guess the signal in this problem is stationary for frames longer than 45 ms, but I need a way to measure this.